# Draw the borders of a binary Numpy array with Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using image-segmentation on some images, and sometimes it would be nice to be able to plot the borders of the segments.

I have a 2D NumPy array that I plot with Matplotlib, and the closest I've gotten, is using contour-plotting. 
This makes corners in the array, but is otherwise perfect.

Can Matplotlib's contour-function be made to only plot vertical/horizontal lines, or is there some other way to do this?

An example can be seen here:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


array = np.zeros((20, 20))
array[4:7, 3:8] = 1
array[4:7, 12:15] = 1
array[7:15, 7:15] = 1
array[12:14, 13:14] = 0

plt.imshow(array, cmap='binary')
plt.contour(array, levels=[0.5], colors='g')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Whoops, thought I already had :I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote some functions to achieve this some time ago, but I would be glad to figure out how it can be done quicker.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


def get_all_edges(bool_img):
    """
    Get a list of all edges (where the value changes from True to False) in the 2D boolean image.
    The returned array edges has he dimension (n, 2, 2).
    Edge i connects the pixels edges[i, 0, :] and edges[i, 1, :].
    Note that the indices of a pixel also denote the coordinates of its lower left corner.
    """
    edges = []
    ii, jj = np.nonzero(bool_img)
    for i, j in zip(ii, jj):
        # North
        if j == bool_img.shape[1]-1 or not bool_img[i, j+1]:
            edges.append(np.array([[i, j+1],
                                   [i+1, j+1]]))
        # East
        if i == bool_img.shape[0]-1 or not bool_img[i+1, j]:
            edges.append(np.array([[i+1, j],
                                   [i+1, j+1]]))
        # South
        if j == 0 or not bool_img[i, j-1]:
            edges.append(np.array([[i, j],
                                   [i+1, j]]))
        # West
        if i == 0 or not bool_img[i-1, j]:
            edges.append(np.array([[i, j],
                                   [i, j+1]]))

    if not edges:
        return np.zeros((0, 2, 2))
    else:
        return np.array(edges)


def close_loop_edges(edges):
    """
    Combine thee edges defined by 'get_all_edges' to closed loops around objects.
    If there are multiple disconnected objects a list of closed loops is returned.
    Note that it's expected that all the edges are part of exactly one loop (but not necessarily the same one).
    """

    loop_list = []
    while edges.size != 0:

        loop = [edges[0, 0], edges[0, 1]]  # Start with first edge
        edges = np.delete(edges, 0, axis=0)

        while edges.size != 0:
            # Get next edge (=edge with common node)
            ij = np.nonzero((edges == loop[-1]).all(axis=2))
            if ij[0].size > 0:
                i = ij[0][0]
                j = ij[1][0]
            else:
                loop.append(loop[0])
                # Uncomment to to make the start of the loop invisible when plotting
                # loop.append(loop[1])
                break

            loop.append(edges[i, (j + 1) % 2, :])
            edges = np.delete(edges, i, axis=0)

        loop_list.append(np.array(loop))

    return loop_list


def plot_outlines(bool_img, ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    edges = get_all_edges(bool_img=bool_img)
    edges = edges - 0.5  # convert indices to coordinates; TODO adjust according to image extent
    outlines = close_loop_edges(edges=edges)
    cl = LineCollection(outlines, **kwargs)
    ax.add_collection(cl)


array = np.zeros((20, 20))
array[4:7, 3:8] = 1
array[4:7, 12:15] = 1
array[7:15, 7:15] = 1
array[12:14, 13:14] = 0

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(array, cmap='binary')
plot_outlines(array.T, lw=5, color='r')
```

[image: Draw the borders of a binary Numpy array with Matplotlib]

Comment: This is nice, thanks !

I did have one problem with non-square images, since you use `grid_size = bool_img.shape[0]`, and if the north and east are different in size, this crashes.
Instead, I use `grid_size_x, grid_size_y = bool_img.shape`, and changing the north/east checks to `if j == grid_size_y - 1 or not bool_img[i, j + 1]:` and  `if i == grid_size_x - 1 or not bool_img[i + 1, j]:`

Otherwise, it works like a charm !

Comment: True, in my case I had only square images, didn't pay attention to the genral case. I updated my answer