# How to find the number of neighbours pixels in binary array

Tags: python

I am looking for an easy way to count the number of the green pixels in the image below, where the original image is the same but the green pixels are black.

I tried it with `numpy.diff()`, but then I am counting some pixels twice. I thought about `numpy.gradient()` – but here I am not sure if it is the right tool.

I know there have to be many solutions to this problem, but I don't know how to google for it. I am looking for a solution in python.

[image: Image with a T]

To make it clearer, I have only one image (only black and white pixels). The image with the green pixel is just for illustration.

Comment: So you have two images? And you want to count the pixels that are green in one but black in the other image?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would like to have a function that takes a binary image as an input and returns a list of all edge pixels. I think the answer on this question is what you're looking for. Please note it is not that efficient but it definitely is simple.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095053/draw-the-borders-of-a-binary-numpy-array-with-matplotlib

Comment: I only want to count the pixels, this answer is to inefficient for me

Comment: Your image is incoherent : the tops of the T have the diagonals cells counted, while the inner short line of 3 do not have the diagonal cells included. Please refine your definition of neighbor pixels and edit the image accordingly.

Comment: @sybog64 Thanks, you are rigth! I changed the image

Comment: To be clear, the rule is that you want to count black pixels *that are adjacent to a white pixel*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [edge detection kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) for this problem.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 1]])

kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                   [-1,  8, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1]])
```

Then, we will convolve the original array with the kernel. Notice that the edges are all negatives.

```py
>>> convolve(a, kernel)
[[-1 -2 -3 -3]
 [-2  5  3  3]
 [-3  3  0  0]]
```

We will count the number of negative values and get the result.

```py
>>> np.where(convolve(a, kernel) < 0, 1, 0)
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]]

>>> np.sum(np.where(convolve(a, kernel) < 0, 1, 0))
6
```

---

### Edges-only kernel

There are a lot of things you can do with the kernel. For example, you can modify the kernel if you don't want to include diagonal neighbors.

```py
kernel = np.array([[ 0, -1,  0],
                   [-1,  4, -1],
                   [ 0, -1,  0]])
```

This gives the following output.

```py
>>> np.where(convolve(a, kernel) < 0, 1, 0)
[[0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]]

>>> np.sum(np.where(convolve(a, kernel) < 0, 1, 0))
5
```

Comment: would switching to excluded diagonal neighbors be as simple as setting them to 0 in the kernel ?

Comment: @sybog64 Yes, you can use the `np.array([[ 0, -1, 0], [-1, 4, -1], [0, -1, 0]])` kernel if you don't want to include diagonal neighbors.

Comment: This answer is perfect!